# combining BehaviorSubjects in rxjs

Tags: rxjs

I would like to combine two BehaviorSubjects with combineLatest(). However, this produces a normal Observer, which does not work for my situation because I need a broadcast stream that emits previous value on listen.

How can I combine multiple BehaviorSubjects into a single BehaviorSubject?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Can you share some code with an actual behavior and desired behavior ? Have you already thought about using `ReplaySubject` or other replay operators ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd create separate BehaviorSubject that would gather emissions from the main two and re-emit them or provide as a value:

```
bs1 = new BehaviorSubject(1);
bs2 = new BehaviorSubject(2);
bsCombined = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);

bs1.subscribe(val => bsCombined.next(val));
bs2.subscribe(val => bsCombined.next(val));

bsCombined.subscribe(newestVal => {
   if(newestVal !== undefined) {
     /* Go on with processing */
   }
})
/* Due to previous subscriptions those emissions will be stored in combined behaviorSubject */
bs1.next(2);
bs1.next(3);
bs2.next(6);
bs1.next(4);
```